# Use MLLib in Spark with Missing Values

Tags: python, null, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of about 70 columns. It is stored as a tsv. Here is how I read it in using Python:

```
txtFiles = sc.textFile("temp/txtFiles/*") \
    .map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
```

This reads in the file and then splits along the tabs into 70 columns. Ideally, the next part of my code would look something like this:

```
asDouble = txtFiles.map(lambda y: MISSING VALUE if len(x) == 0 \
    else float(x) for x in y)
```

As of right now, I cannot achieve this. If I want to create an RDD that maintains missing values, it must be an array of type "Any" and it holds the NAs as strings and the numeric values as doubles.

Here is the crux of my issue: I want to convert each row into a LabeledPoint object, along these lines:

```
lblPt = asDouble.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[70], x[0:69]))
```

However, since my data in asDouble is actually of type "Any," it will not let me transform it into a set of LabeledPoints. LabeledPoint objects require doubles only.

Is there a way to encode missing values in RDD's such that the RDD can be used in various machine learning problems such as decision trees, naive bayes, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being coding the `missing value` I wanted as `None`. However, `len` wasn't working as I had hoped. Instead, I realized that my data had missing values coded as `'NaN'`.
So my solution looked like this:

```
txtFiles = sc.textFile("temp/txtFiles/*") \
    .map(lambda x: x.split("\t"))
asDouble = txtFiles.map(lambda y: None if x == 'Nan' \
    else float(x) for x in y)
lblPt = asDouble.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[70], x[0:69]))
```

I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how missing values were stored in my original dataset (I thought they were empty strings when really they were stored as `'NaN'`(a string). I also needed to find the keyword `None`.

Comment: Were you able to run the ML algorithms after this fix? If that is the case, which algorithms run with missing values (they must internally be using surrogate splits). I am not aware of Spark algorithms that handle missing values, maybe they have recently updated.

Comment: @Earnest_learner, there are lots of algorithms that work with missing values! Naive Bayes, Decision Trees, and Random Forests can all be executed with missing data for classification problems.